# Notepad ++ RegEx Repetition Syntax

Tags: regex, notepad++, repeat

Imagine I have a word 'bananananas'. What would be the RegEx repetition syntax to find this word:

So far, I tried `ba(na){4}s`, but it yielded no results. What is the correct syntax to do so please?

Comment: Your regex will only work in Notepad++ starting from version 6, which supports PCRE and thus supports numeric quantifiers. Previous versions will spit an error.

Comment: I'm running v6.1.1, and the regex you listed works.  So I suspect @BoltClock is correct.

Comment: Ok so the syntax is correct then. Let me update the notepad++ and tell you. Thanks guys

Comment: You're right. It was because of the Notepad++ version. I donwloaded the latest version (6.1.2) and it worked perfectly :) Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, your regex will only work in Notepad++ starting from version 6, which supports PCRE and thus supports numeric quantifiers. Previous versions will spit an error.

If you're using an older version and for some reason cannot upgrade, you won't be able to use that syntax. You'll have to put up with something like `ba(na)+s` instead, which matches `na` repeated as many times as until it reaches `s`.

Comment: +1, since it's correct, and since I'm not sure you're gonna get the points from the anonymous poster.